# Which longitudinal data analysis is appropriate?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, stata, glmm, generalized-estimating-equations

I would like to test the effect of anxiety (binary measure) on alcohol consumption (in four categories). I have anxiety data only at baseline and alcohol data several times during follow-up, but with unevenly spaced measurement times (and not the same number of follow-ups for each subject).

1) Conceptually, I understood that there was a difference between mean population models (like GEE) and subject specific models (like GLMM) but I have trouble knowing which one would be most appropriate.

2) On the practical side, I do not know whether there is a model for managing a multinomial outcome (especially in the case of irregular delays between measures), if possible on STATA.